# Отправка checkbox + input на почту

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, sendmail

Есть форма

```
 <div class="checkbox_social">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_social_item" id="facebook" /><label for="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>facebook</label>
    <input class="social_adres" type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Ссылка на соцсеть" />
  </div>
........
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_social_item" id="vk" /><label for="vk"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>vk</label>
    <input class="social_adres" type="text" name="vk" placeholder="Ссылка на соцсеть" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Как мне отправить выбранный чекбокс и данные из соответствующего инпута на почту?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php